# Получуние курса доллара через json + php

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте, имею такой код:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
print_r($obj);

?>
```

он получает данные от ПриватБанк в таком виде:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ccy] => USD [base_ccy] => UAH [buy] => 26.50000 [sale] => 26.85000 ) [1] => Array ( [ccy] => EUR [base_ccy] => UAH [buy] => 32.20000 [sale] => 32.70000 ) [2] => Array ( [ccy] => RUR [base_ccy] => UAH [buy] => 0.46000 [sale] => 0.49000 ) [3] => Array ( [ccy] => BTC [base_ccy] => USD [buy] => 10136.3718 [sale] => 11203.3583 ) )
```

мне нужно из этого в 2 переменные получить курс доллара к гривне
то есть чила: 26.50000 и 26.85000, что бы в итоге у меня было 2 переменные $kurs_buy $kurs_sale .
Весь мозг продолбал, но как выьрать от туда эти значения понять не могу

Comment: код работает, но выводит 7 символов - везде. как вывести первые 4 символа. тоесть 00.00 а не 00.00000. теряется вся эстетика и занимает много места если три валюты в одну строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$kurs_buy = $kurs_sale = 0;
foreach ($obj as $item) {
    if ($item['ccy'] == 'USD' && $item['base_ccy'] == 'UAH') {
        $kurs_buy = $item['buy'];
        $kurs_sale = $item['sale'];
        continue;
    }
}

echo "buy: {$kurs_buy} - sale: {$kurs_sale}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял

```
$url = 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

echo 'Покупка <br>';
echo '1 USD = '.$obj[0]['buy'].' UAH <br>';
echo '1 EUR = '.$obj[1]['buy'].' UAH <br>';
echo '1 RUR = '.$obj[2]['buy'].' UAH <br>';

echo '<br> Продажа <br>';
echo '1 USD = '.$obj[0]['sale'].' UAH <br>';
echo '1 EUR = '.$obj[1]['sale'].' UAH <br>';
echo '1 RUR = '.$obj[2]['sale'].' UAH <br>';

echo '<br>';
echo '1 USD - Покупка: '.$obj[0]['buy'].' UAH, Продажа: '.$obj[0]['sale'].' UAH<br>';
echo '1 EUR - Покупка: '.$obj[1]['buy'].' UAH, Продажа: '.$obj[1]['sale'].' UAH<br>';
echo '1 RUR - Покупка: '.$obj[2]['buy'].' UAH, Продажа: '.$obj[2]['sale'].' UAH<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте готовое решение для получения курсов валют из банков Украины

https://github.com/pavlovich-app/KursToday-API

Есть возможность получать курс валют из банков и обменников Украины.

Установка и использование Composer пакета очень проста:

```
composer require kurstoday/api
```

Использование:

```
<?php use kurstoday\Kurstoday; // подключаем класс

$kurstoday = new Kurstoday; // создаем экземпляр класса
$lutskService = $kurstoday->getService('banks-of-ukraine'); // получаем курс валют в банках Украины
```

Пример ответа:

```
[
    [serviceId] => 3
    [serviceName] => Lutsk
    [exchangers] => [ // обменники (банки)
        [0] => [
            [id] => 1
            [serviceId] => 3
            [name] => Kantor
            [website] => http://kantor.com.ua
            [image] => https://kurstoday.com/images/exchangers/kantor.png // логотип обменника (банка)
            [background] => #00A1D8
            [border] => #969696
            [slug] => kantor
            [rates] => [ // описание курсов валют
                [exchangerId] => 72
                [updateTime] => 1588581967 // время в формате timestamp (Europe/Kiev) последнего изменения курса
                [usd] => [
                    [buy] => 27.00
                    [sel] => 27.10
                ],
                [eur] => [
                    [buy] => 29.20
                    [sel] => 29.40
                ],
                ... и так дальше ...
            ],
        ],
        ... и так дальше ...
    ]
]
```